# Rails 4 and Stripe Card Processing Error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I'm new to Rails and I have spent a good chunk of today struggling with the following issue. I'm integrating Stripe into my Rails application. All was going well until I try to actually finish the order and I get the following error in my local host

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError in OrdersController#create
You must supply either a card or a customer id
```

I have tried various fixes all to no avail including disabling turbolinks on the whole app. I will really appreciate any help I can get since I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I have attached the relevant code below

Orders Controller

```
def create
@order = Order.new(order_params)
@place = Place.find(params[:place_id])
@seller = @place.user

@order.place_id = @place.id
@order.buyer_id = current_user.id
@order.seller_id = @seller.id

Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
token = params[:stripeToken]

puts "Token is #{token}"

begin
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => (@place.rating * 100).floor,
    :currency => "usd",
    :card => token
    )
  flash[:notice] = "Thanks for ordering!"
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:danger] = e.message
end

  respond_to do |format|
  if @order.save
    format.html { redirect_to root_url }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# FURTHER DOWN BELOW 

private
def set_order
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end

def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:address, :city, :state, :card_number, :card_code, :'data-stripe' )
end
end
```

CoffeeScript

```
jQuery ->
Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
payment.setupForm()

payment = 
setupForm: ->
    $('#new_order').submit ->
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
        Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_order'), payment.handleStripeResponse)
        false

handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
        $('#new_order').append($('<input-type="hidden" name="stripeToken"/>').val(response.id))
        $('#new_order')[0].submit()
    else
        $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message).show()
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

Orders View

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, {:name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "number" , class: "form-control" } %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= label_tag :card_code, "CVC" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, {:name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "cvc" , class: "form-control" } %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag nil, "Expiration Date" %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= select_month nil, { use_two_digit_numbers: true }, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "exp-month", class: "form-control"} %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= select_year nil, { start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+10 }, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "exp-year", class: "form-control"} %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Also upon another recommendation, I added the following

```
puts "Token is #{token}"
```

to the controller and I get

```
Token is _____
```

So I get a blank space in the terminal next to where the token is. Is the token not passing through here or what is going on?

Can anyone please help me to solve this? I'm not sure what to do anymore and I have spent the better half of today on this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Is that the real indentation in your CoffeeScript?

Comment: @muistooshort No, it's just the way Stack Overflow formats it, ill give you a screenshot 

http://imgur.com/lu6crxW

Comment: Are you really using `<input-type="hidden"`? Shouldn't it be `<input type="hidden"`?

Comment: @muistooshort WOW, can't believe I missed this, this did the trick ... Thank you so much!

Comment: @Richard Seviora, thanks for your reply, I think in this case, the cause was just a stupid typo on my behalf that I overlooked and spent a whole day looking elsewhere for the fix ...

Answer (score 0):

The `createToken` method requires [a JS object with number and expiry date values](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js). I don't believe you're sending those to it. Try passing those explicitly, and putting breakpoints after the method in your browser debugger to see what happens.